# How to use npm commands using vs code terminal?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio

I'm trying to use npm commands on my vs code terminal but whenever I use this command it will open a blank file. I already install node.js and these commands are working on cmd but not working on Vs code terminal why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend installing Ubuntu terminal extension, and then you'll have Ubuntu Bash running on your VSCode without any problem.